# How to read two bytes from SerialPort in C#?

Tags: c#, serial-port

I try to send and receive some data using [SerialPort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.io.ports.serialport(v=vs.110).aspx) in C#. I notices a behavior I considered strange when trying to receive some data.

If I use code like this:

```
Byte[] receiveData = new Byte[2];
port.Read(receiveData, 0, 2);
BitArray array = new BitArray(receiveData);
```

then the `array` will contain just the first byte, and the second one will be only zeros (in spite of other data being sent.) However, such modification:

```
Byte[] receiveData = new Byte[2];
port.Read(receiveData, 0, 1);
port.Read(receiveData, 1, 1);
BitArray array = new BitArray(receiveData);
```

Results in correct array contents. Should receiving 1 byte twice differ from receiving 2 bytes once, as it happens here?

Comment: Did you check the return value of Read()?

Comment: You are right, thanks! Couldn't find the other post (naming :(), should I remove this one or keep for others?

Comment: Just keep this one, so others finding your question through a web search can find the original. :)